# sendmail doesn't send email to specific domain email address

Tags: email-server, sendmail, ubuntu-12.04

We have ubuntu 12.04 server and installed sendmail to send mails from this server.

**Problem:**

There is some strange issue on mail server. Somehow, server not able to send email to `xxx@ayolla.com`

but server sends email successfully to other email ids like `xxx@spaceotechnologies.com`, `xxx@gmail.com` or `xxx@yahoo.com`.

**Success Case: when send email to xxx@spaceotechnologies.com**

```
Dec 28 11:40:49 ip-10-99-66-252 sm-mta[16954]: qBSBemdx016952: to=<xxx@spaceotechnologies.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ayolla.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120352, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.131.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1356694874 d3si34930711vdv.119)
Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252 sendmail[16960]: qBSBphki016960: from=www-data, size=89, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212281151.qBSBphki016960@ayolla.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
```

**Fail Case: when send email to xxx@ayolla.com**

```
Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252 sm-mta[16962]: qBSBphSo016962: <xxx@ayolla.com>... User unknown Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252 sendmail[16960]: qBSBphki016960: to=info@ayolla.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30089, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

Can someone please help to sort out this issue ?

**Edit:**
I have removed sendmail from server and re-installed it. now i am getting following in mail.log when sends mail to xxx@ayolla.com

```
Dec 29 09:34:32 ip-10-99-66-252 sm-mta[1773]: qBT9YWGZ001771: to=<xxx@ayolla.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@ip-10-99-66-252.ec2.internal> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120393, relay=mx.ayolla.com. [66.96.142.51], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
```

Note: I don't want to expose our emails that's why i replaced xxx with original email address into this question.

Comment: Can you include some of you sendmail.mc file?

Comment: where i should get this file ?

Comment: I got sendmail.mc file but what should i paste from this file ?

Comment: The error message says "User unknown".  Are you able to send emails to that user from another place, such as Gmail?

Comment: Yes, tried to send email through gmail account. it was successfully sent.But when i tried same thing from server, it gets fail

Comment: @Ladadadada see updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration has changed after you re-installed sendmail.  Before, it was trying to relay email for this domain via itself. (`relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1]`)  i.e. Your mail server was asking itself to send mail.

Now, it's correctly doing the MX lookup and trying to send via the mail servers for `ayolla.com` (`relay=mx.ayolla.com. [66.96.142.51]`).

The trouble seems to be that it can't connect to `66.96.142.51`.  (Or, presumably the other two: `66.96.142.50` and `66.96.142.52`.)

Try `telnet 66.96.142.51 25` from your server to see if you can connect.  An instant fail or a timeout means that there's either a network route that's not correct or a firewall that's not allowing this traffic.  If you are sure it's not at your end, it's must be at their end.