# sendmail fails to send to specifc domains with "stat User unknown"

Tags: sendmail, ubuntu-14.04

First of all, I searched a lot and the closest scenario found is [sendmail doesn't send email to specific domain email address](https://serverfault.com/questions/461605/sendmail-doesnt-send-email-to-specific-domain-email-address), tried to use the proposed solutions but none of them worked for me.

I've setup sendmail on Ubuntu 14.04 on an Amazon EC2 instance.
I can send e-mails to gmail, hotmail, etc. But to some servers i can't, and get a `dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown`, but the recipient exists.

Above some lines from `/etc/log/mail.log`:

**Success case** (to gmail.com)

```
Oct 14 12:58:34 localhost sendmail[14297]: s9EFwYfI014297: to=user@gmail.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30402, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s9EFwYZH014298 Message accepted for delivery)
Oct 14 12:58:34 localhost sm-mta[14300]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,  bits=128/128
Oct 14 12:58:34 localhost sm-mta[14300]: s9EFwYZH014298: to=<user@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120677, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.22.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1413302456 f80si4956341qge.106 - gsmtp)
```

**Failure case**

```
Oct 14 13:11:39 localhost sendmail[23047]: s9EGBdn7023047: to=user@broken-domain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30399, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s9EGBdYs023048 Message accepted for delivery)
Oct 14 13:11:39 localhost sm-mta[23050]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.broken-domain.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Oct 14 13:11:39 localhost sm-mta[23050]: s9EGBdYs023048: to=<user@broken-domain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120674, relay=broken-domain.com. [1.2.3.4], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

Additional info:

- Tried to telnet the server using `telnet 1.2.3.4 25` and connected successfully.
- I have only CPanel access to *brokendomail.com*, so I'm pretty sure the destination email address exists.
- the origin (EC2 instance) is a subdomain (*dev.brokenserver.com*) resolved through a CNAME record to the public DNS

Until now I'm not able to figure out why this error occurs. Appreciate any help.

Note: I changed the emails, domains and IP that are not public, for privacy :)

### UPDATE

I run the commands from Eugene's answer (command - status):

- telnet - 200
- HELO - 250
- MAIL FROM - 250
- RCPT TO - 550

Indeed the relay tells that the user doesn't exist.

Investigating the destination server i've found the solution:

Subdomain dev.brokenserver.com was remaining in the destination server, treating that as local address, so the server was blocking the access.

Removing the subdomain through CPanel solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your destination relay tells you that the user doesn't exist. You could emulate easily and investigate if it's true:

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 25
[relay will say something like 220 broken-domain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.9/8.14.5; Thu, 16 Oct 2014 17:14:14 +0600 (PST)]
HELO dev.brokenserver.com
[let's hope relay will answer with a 250]
MAIL FROM: root@dev.brokenserver.com
[let's hope again this will be enough to get a 250 from remote relay]
RCPT TO: user@broken-domain.com
[and _here_ you will get the result about whether user exists or not]
```

If I'm right then you will have to investigate the user visibility problem on a remote relay.